# Will continuing to use Google Adsense on my old, not as good, website hurt the ad revenue from the new better site?

Tags: google, google-adsense

I currently have my AdSense account linked to two websites. One of which was a site before I knew the importance of SEO.

Now that I have a new website that has quality content and written to conform to SEO standards if my Page RPM will be bought down by my old web site still being linked and having terrible SEO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have adsense for a long time, you create advert blocks, these blocks are independent of each other. So, you can still old advert to old page, and create new advert blocks to new page. The bot of google adsense read the content of page and with cookies show the advert more adecuate to visitors.
The RPM its independent for each page, and are based on you ads shows (impressions) to visitors and clicks in ads, ads clicks are the key to improve.